# adding html and javascript function in c# but looks different in asp page and doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm using this code to add it to my asp page

```
var func = $@"var tbl= document.getElementById('table{obj.ID}');
if(tbl.style.display === 'none') {{tbl.style.display = 'block';}} 
else {{tbl.style.display = 'none';}}
```

when i check the value in add watch through debugging it's value be as follow

```
var tbl= document.getElementById('table38'); if(tbl.style.display === 'none') {tbl.style.display = 'block';} else {tbl.style.display = 'none';}
```

then i add this function to my button

```
sb.AppendFormat(@"<button type='button' width='100px' onClick='{0}' > view {1} comments' </button>", func, lst.Count);
```

but in my page in browser this function doesn't work 
and when i use the inspect element it's look like this 
not what i added in my code

```
<button type="button" width="100px" onclick="var tbl= document.getElementById(" table28');="" if(tbl.style.display="==" 'none')="" {tbl.style.display="block" ;}="" else="" ;}'=""> view 3 comments' </button>
```

I tried it outside but using it directly in my asp page and it's work fine

Comment: You should go back to square one and 1) ask yourself why you are injecting HTML and JavaScript this way 2) using string interpolation and 3) why you are not using a JavaScript function in a `<script>` block.

Comment: I'm using dynamic table  and this function in each row